# MySQL DB Migration from on-premises to AWS through replication

Tags: mysql-5.6, migration, amazon-rds

I am having a production MySQL server with set of 20 databases in on-premises server. Now I require to migrate few databases from production server to AWS RDS without disturbing other databases in one-by-one.

We can perform this activity using AWS DMS. Instead, I am looking at tranditional MySQL replication for setting up replication between existing production server to AWS RDS.

In RDS, as we are not having access to my.cnf, I am not able to set replicate-do-db configuration. Is there any other workaround to setup replication from on-premises to RDS for few databases.

Comment: you would probably need an intermediate slave server where the replicate-wild-ignore-db is set and then let AWS RDS instance connect to this intermediate slave to replicate all databases, basically, the 'filtering' happens on the intermediate slave server

Comment: Actual requirement is replicate databases from one production server to multiple instances and split the production server. So we can't create multiple slaves for each RDS instance. Also we need to have all databases in sync all the time.

Comment: another option you may try is tungsten replicator. just thought it might work in your use case

Answer (score 0):

Here's pretty detailed blog post about how to do this:

[How to Migrate to MySQL RDS Without Downtime](https://workmarket.tech/how-to-migrate-to-mysql-rds-without-downtime-e771c26a548b)

> Our approach was to configure M/M replication between our MySQL instance hosted on EC2 and the new RDS, then gracefully switch traffic from our application servers one at a time without any downtime for our customers.
>
> To clarify, the Non-RDS server in this article refers to MySQL instance running either in your data center or on an Amazon EC2 instance